# Selenium Could Not Locate Element by XPath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to locate element using Xpath with Selenium.

The element in question is the channel name on the YouTube page: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FSyAehMdpyI&list=PL8dPuuaLjXtPHzzYuWy6fYEaX9mQQ8oGr

My xpath is:

```
/html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[7]/div[3]/ytd-video-secondary-info-renderer/div/div[2]/ytd-video-owner-renderer/div[1]/div/yt-formatted-string/a
```

In the developer tool bar on the YouTube page, I was able to find the element by entering the Xpath. But when I try to find it in my Python script the operation times out.

```
channel_name = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/ytd-page-manager/ytd-watch-flexy/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[7]/div[3]/ytd-video-secondary-info-renderer/div/div[2]/ytd-video-owner-renderer/div[1]/div/yt-formatted-string/a"))).text
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Try a simpler Xpath `//ytd-video-owner-renderer/div/div/yt-formatted-string/a`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This one,

Relative path - `//yt-formatted-string[@id='owner-name']//a[contains(text(),'CrashCourse')]`

it Worked for me, Hope it Helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a much simpler *relative xpath* to extract the **channel name** using **`visibility_of_element_located()`** method and you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using `text`:

  ```
  channel_name = self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='owner-container']/yt-formatted-string[@id='owner-name']/a"))).text
  ```
- Using `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  channel_name = self.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='owner-container']/yt-formatted-string[@id='owner-name']/a"))).get_attribute("innerHTML")
  ```